# Where is the doc of object parameters of electric & fuerte gazebo?

Tags: ros, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [simulator_gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials) tutorials.

I run

```
  rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file `pwd`/object.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model my_object
```

Where are those parameters document?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34343/where-is-the-doc-of-object-parameters-of-electric-&-fuerte-gazebo?/) by [li-an](https://answers.ros.org/users/2411/li-an/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run
rosrun gazebo spawn_model

then you get some description of the parameters

```
-[urdf|gazebo|trimesh] - specify incoming xml is urdf or gazebo format
-[file|param] [<file_name>|<param_name>] - source of the model xml or the trimesh file
-model <model_name> - name of the model to be spawned.
-z <z in meters> - optional: initial pose, use 0 if left out
```

---

Originally posted by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) with karma: 544 on 2012-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0